# How to set a minimum range on the y-axis for a stacked area chart in d3

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts, nvd3.js

I'm creating a stacked chart using nvd3, similar to [the example on the nvd3 website](http://nvd3.org/examples/stackedArea.html).

However, my data set is a lot more uniform than their example; I'm actually visualizing a funnel with multiple steps over time, each step describing the % that made it from the last step to this one, so it ranges from 100% to about 80%. So it ends up just looking like 4 straight rectangles (see below).

[image: funnel chart]

I'd like to know if there is some way of setting a minimum value to display on the y-axis so that each step only takes into account the data that is actually likely to fluctuate, leading to a clearer indication of peaks and troughs.

I've tried using `.range([100, 80])` and `.domain([80, 100])` but neither seems to make any difference.

For example:
    var y = d3.scale.linear().range([100, 80]);

```
chart.yAxis
  .scale(y)
  .tickFormat(d3.format(',.2f'));
```

Full code for my example is [available here](https://github.com/francisbyrne/d3-stacked-chart-yrange).

Any ideas how to achieve this?